# Symfony Normalizer and ArrayCollections

Tags: php, symfony, oop, doctrine-orm

I am passing an ArrayCollection to a custom Symfony Normalizer:

```
$container = new ArrayCollection();
$container->set('root', $processor->getFile());

$container->get('root')->each(function($node) {
    $container->set('node', $node);
    $data = $this->serializer->normalize($container);
});
```

The collection contains two Symfony Crawler pointers. A pointer to the root object and the current pointer in the loop (current node) so i can pull data from parents as well as the current child.

Now when I `var_dump()` this in my (interfaced) `supportsNormalization()` function I get 3 separate objects:

1. \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
2. \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler
3. \DOMElement

Of course, I just want the object I passed. Is this some sort of bubbling?

Thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel Diez ArrayCollections are part of the Doctrine Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually get all nested objects.

This is a feature of Symfony's Normalizer... When passing objects to the `normalize()` function Symfony recursively calls `normalize()` on all nested objects until `supportsNormalization()` finds a match.

https://github.com/symfony/serializer/blob/master/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php